# Trouble with View Unit Testing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

In doing some research on AngularJS component testing I've read about **View Unit Testing**, as described [here](https://medium.com/@carmelc_20450/testing-angular-components-you-dont-know-what-you-re-missing-149a1cae6668). I've tried it this way:

### component

```
angular.module("recipeDetail").component("recipeSummary", {
  templateUrl:
    "modules/recipe-detail/recipe-summary/recipe-summary.template.html",
  bindings: { recipe: "<" },
  controller: function RecipeSummaryController() {}
});
```

### template

```js
<h1 id="recipe-title">{{ $ctrl.recipe.title }}</h1>
<p>
  Steps:
</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="step in $ctrl.recipe.steps" class="recipe-summary-step">
    {{ step.text }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

### test

```
describe("recipeSummary ViewUnitTest", () => {
  let scope;
  let $compile;
  beforeEach(module("recipeDetail"));

  beforeEach(inject(($rootScope, _$compile_) => {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile = _$compile_;
  }));

  it("should display the steps", () => {
    scope.recipe = recipe;
    let el = angular.element('<recipe-summary recipe="recipe"/>');
    el = $compile(el)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    expect(el[0].querySelectorAll("p").length).toBe(1); // to make sure this whole thing is working 
    expect(el[0].querySelectorAll(".recipe-summary-step").length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

Both assertions fail – both the first (`p`) that checks that I'm implementing the test correctly, and the second (`.recipe-summary-step`) which tests the actual function of the component.

### UPDATE

Well don't I feel dumb. George pointed out that I didn't actually *call* `scope.$digest()`.

So after doing that I have a new error/failure:

```
Chrome 74.0.3729 (Mac OS X 10.14.4) recipeSummary ViewUnitTest should display the steps FAILED
        Error: Unexpected request: GET modules/recipe-detail/recipe-summary/recipe-summary.template.html
        No more request expected
        error properties: Object({ $$passToExceptionHandler: true })
            at createFatalError (/Users/TuzsNewMacBook/Development/code/AngularJS/recipe-angular-from-phonecat/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1569:19)
            at $httpBackend (/Users/TuzsNewMacBook/Development/code/AngularJS/recipe-angular-from-phonecat/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1616:11)
            at sendReq (lib/angular/angular.js:13257:9)
            at serverRequest (lib/angular/angular.js:12998:16)
            at processQueue (lib/angular/angular.js:17914:37)
            at lib/angular/angular.js:17962:27
            at ChildScope.$digest (lib/angular/angular.js:19075:15)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (modules/recipe-detail/recipe-summary/recipe-summary.component.spec.js:32:11)
            at <Jasmine>
```

Apparently a `templateUrl` is resolved with an actual `get` request and apparently that's a fatal error. So how do I use this technique?

Comment: The code is simulating the binding with the third argument of the [`$componentController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$componentController) service.

Comment: I actually did figure that out. But I can't figure out how to get around it!

Comment: `querySelectorAll` does not find the "recipe-summary" tag *inside* `el[0]` because `el[0]` is itself the "recipe-summary" element.

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg that makes a lot of sense! However, notice the new assertion I've added to my post, which is also failing. (You can see the template which I've added as well.) I tried  `expect(el[0].querySelectorAll("p").length).toBe(1);` which also fails!

Comment: The p tag assertion is just in the comment. The p tags in the [second] template are around the text “Steps”.

Comment: The `$digest` property of the `scope` object is a method. It needs to be invoked, e.g. `scope.$digest()`.

Comment: Well don't I feel dumb. Please see my update for the new error that comes up. And thanks for your help!